# What is this linear movement mechanism called?

Tags: mechanisms

Does anyone know what this mechanism for linear movement is called? I have a different model of something like this, and the black chain appears rigid, so I assume it is the mechanism moving the laser head. I could be wrong though.

[image: The mechanism in question.]

Comment: It's not clear from the picture. However the black chain-like devise is used to manage wires.

Comment: @EricShain I just searched for "linear actuator cable management chain" and found the chain part. Apparently it's called a "cable chain". You can post it as an answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The head probably moves by rack and pinion or a hidden timing belt.

The cable management is done by a [cable carrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cable_carrier). It works by having each joint only have a limited rotation so that it can support itself when held horizontally.